# Where xterm Escape sequences like "Esc | 112 m" are defined?

Tags: windows, vim, xterm, ansi-escape

While implementing xterm-256-colors in ConEmu I have discovered some unknown for me Escape sequences (used by Vim) like

```
Esc | 7 m
Esc | 15 m
Esc | 112 m
```

From Vim sources I realize that these codes are used for changing bold or inverse attributes, but I can't find any docs about them.

Are there any specifications for `Esc | N m` sequences? They were not mentioned [here](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html).

Comment: For what it's worth, they were unlikely to be xterm sequences since they were (a) not legacy and (b) not ECMA-48 format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe these are internal vim codes for internal processing only: first set of `\033|` is labeled

```
/*
 * GUI pseudo term-cap.
 */
```

and AFAIR is processed in `gui.c` or `gui_*.c`, second set is labeled

```
/*
 * These codes are valid for the pc video.  The entries that start with ESC |
 * are translated into conio calls in os_msdos.c. Default for MSDOS.
 */
```

third set is labeled

```
/*
 * These codes are valid for the Win32 Console .  The entries that start with
 * ESC | are translated into console calls in os_win32.c.  The function keys
 * are also translated in os_win32.c.
 */
```

(I am talking about [`builtin_termcaps` array](https://bitbucket.org/ZyX_I/vim/src/9e415188331c2f84e11fe759ca554b36fa62ec2e/src/term.c#cl-148)). Further mentions: only in [`update_tcap` function](https://bitbucket.org/ZyX_I/vim/src/9e415188331c2f84e11fe759ca554b36fa62ec2e/src/term.c#cl-5976), there are no direct references that these are processed by some other function, but it is unlikely that it is something else (not familiar with pseudo-termcap processing code). Except for `term.c` it is only seen directly (i.e. grep finds `\033|`) in `screen.c` (twice) and `gui.c` (once).

And, by the way, I failed to see this code in output of vim launched in logging screen session using `env TERM=xterm vim {args}`.